# Reading an excel file from Sharepoint online using REST and the Microsoft Graph API

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, excel-online

Is it possible to read an excel file from Sharepoint online using REST and the Microsoft Graph ? I need to retrieve a column field using javascript/Jquery
Any feedback will be really appreciated

Comment: This question was posted over 3 years ago and still no response..I came across this https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sample-uri-for-excel-services-rest-api but it doesn't show i can retrieve column field i need using javascript/jquery.  Any ideas?